# WebBrowser in C# missing content

Tags: c#

If I use google chrome to view this URL:
http://www.amazon.ca/gp/pdp/profile/A1D2C0WDCSHUWZ

I get the normal page with a link called "See more", if I press on "See more" I see another link called "Send an E-mail". My problem is that when I use the WebBrowser control that is in C# to open the same link I don't see the "Send an E-mail" link but I see the "See more" link. So why is that happening? I need to access the "Send an E-mail" link using the WebBrowser control in the C#.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

So i don't think the web browser is missing any content...

When you are in the webbrowser control in your application are you logged into Amazon? When i tried this myself I see the Send Email link only appears when you are logged in.

Comment: I just checked it, and it looks like this is completely correct. When using the webbrowser control, I see the Send Email link, once I've logged in.